# Make part of php comment line bold in vim

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vimrc, vi

I've a PHP script, and I would like to know if natively, I can make a part of a comment line **BOLD**.

---

For example a comment :

```
// it is released when you execute RELEASE_LOCK(), execute a new GET_LOCK(), or your connection terminates (either normally or abnormally).
```

---

I would like a syntax like this, to make a part of comment bold (only a part, not all line)

`//it is released when you execute RELEASE_LOCK(), execute a new GET_LOCK(),`**`or your connection terminates (either normally or abnormally).`**

Is it possible ? Or should I add some line in vimrc ?

Comment: It is possible to create syntax regions and color them differently. Can you tell me how the exact part looks like, a string or a regex?

Comment: I wanted to bold the part of string in a php comment, exactly like in my exemple